# What's the dependency of import com.facebook.share.internal.ShareConstants;?

Tags: java, android, dependencies

I am trying to find the dependency for this import statement that I obtained from another program but unsuccessful so far.

```
import com.facebook.share.internal.ShareConstants;
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be the Facebook android SDK. If you scroll a bit in the page below, you'll find instructions on how to use it in your project. You might want to inform yourself on the version of the SDK which the program was originally using, though, to avoid compatibility issues.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk